# Linker section alignment

Tags: linker, ld, linker-scripts

I'm trying to write an executable where the .text section is located in a specific location. I wrote the following linker script:

```
base_address = 0x123456789AB;
SECTIONS
{
    ENTRY(_start)
    . = base_address;
    .text : { *(.text); }
}
```

However when I look at the memory mapping of the resulting executable, I see:

```
12345600000-12345679000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1 /path/to/executable
```

It is obvious why the section would be aligned to `0x1000`, that's page size, but where does `0x100000` come from?

Now the interesting part is that this only happens when I disable build ids with `-Wl,--build-id=none`, or when I enable them and try to stuff the `.note.gnu.build-id` section right after `.text`.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue - it seems .text sections will be aligned at megabyte boundaries, no idea why or how to suppress it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the generated map file. It's possible that some of your input .text sections also have their own alignment requirements.